# Something instead of <span> to wrap over an <ul> in a valid way

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I have a dropdown `<ul>` inside a `<span>`. The reason is because I want the dropdown list to be as wide as the `<span>` text using `width: 100%`, and not hard px values, since the  text varies in length on different pages.

Using an `<ul>` inside a `<span>` works but is not valid. What is valid is `<u>, <small>, <b>, <strong>` etc. but they have effects/style on the text which I don't want.

What I need is a dummy element like span, with no effects on the text that I can add my own classes to (for highlight). But it has to be a valid container for an `<ul>`.

Or some other good idea.

Currently:

```
<span class="hightlight"> My highlighted text
   <ul class="dropdown">
       <li> .. </li>
       <li> .. </li>
       <li> .. </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `<div>`?

Comment: Wrap the tags in backticks (\`), otherwise they don't show in the question.

Comment: @Juhana that edit is pending.

Comment: Putting a block level element `ul` inside an inline element like `strong` is not valid.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  I've spent the last 15 hours trying to come up with a response to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<div>` would be the equal. The `<span>` element is basically in inline `<div>` element.

Answer (score 3):

The block-level counterpart of `span` is `div`. Neither of them has any impact on default rendering except that `span` is an inline element, `div` is a block element.

It is not clear why you need a container, since there is presumably some styling that causes some problem that you try to fix with a container. By default, `ul` is full-width, i.e. its width is the available width, i.e. `width: 100%`. And you can assign a class and properties directly on the `ul` element.

Regarding the other approaches considered in the question, `u`, `small` etc. cannot contain `ul` any more than `span` can, as per the specs. They have the same content model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DIV` and display it as inline to not disrupt your current flow.

HTML:

```
<div class="hightlight"> My highlighted text
   <ul class="dropdown">
       <li> .. </li>
       <li> .. </li>
       <li> .. </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use strong if you want, and in css specify that `.highlight { font-weight: normal }` so it won't be bold anymore.

Comment: Oh, please do comment why are you downvoting

Comment: Using `<strong>` as a generic container is just... dirty.

Comment: what you find dirty is not the point here. i was pointing that style can be removed if needed. just like you make a `div` to be `inline` you can make a `strong` tag not to bold anything inside it.

Comment: `<strong><ul>...</ul></strong>` is not valid. Changing from `span` to `strong` would create a new problem (bolding), instead of solving any.